# Browser not interpreting my CSS

Tags: python, css, html, flask, jinja2

I'm new to web dev and am working on my first fully custom site built with Flask. I used [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) for the base code structure and [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) to template my pages. Here is the file structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── browserconfig.xml
│   │   ├── crossdomain.xml
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── main.css
│   │   │   └── normalize.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   │   ├── tile-wide.png
│   │   │   └── tile.png
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── main.js
│   │   │   ├── plugins.js
│   │   │   └── vendor
│   │   │       ├── jquery-1.12.0.min.js
│   │   │       └── modernizr-2.8.3.min.js
│   │   └── robots.txt
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   ├── about.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── views.py
├── config.py
├── profile.py
├── run.py
├── tests.py
└── tmp
    └── tmp.log
```

Here is what `base.html` looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <title>{{ title }}</title>

        <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="/static/img/apple-touch-icon" href="/static/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/normalize.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="/static/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/static/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="/static/js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
        <!-- <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the `Author's custom styles` section of `main.css` (html5 boilerplate source [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/css/main.css#L95)) I've added these initial stylings:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Except when I start the server and go to the site, none of the custom styling seems to be taking affect. Some part of the css is definitely working because the site doesn't look like raw html, but my custom styles are not being interpreted. Am I doing something wrong in the html template?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS RESET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) will help you. The actual problem that you have is in the web browser. They change the style attributes, fonts, margins, padding, and many other things by **DEFAULT**. To fix this, you can directly append the following code to your stylesheet that wasn't working as well as you expected:

**Note:** Append the CSS reset **before** you put your code.

```
  html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
  a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
  del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
  small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
  b, u, i, center,
  dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
  fieldset, form, label, legend,
  table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
  article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
  figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
  time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
  article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
  footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
  }
  body {
  line-height: 1;
  }
  ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
  }
  blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
  }
  blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
  q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
  }
  table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  }
  /*Your own CSS code*/
```

Comment: Thank you I'll give this a try. Though isn't this what `normalize.css` is supposed to do? If not, will this overwrite anything there that will hurt the site?